# How can I detect if a dictionary has certain criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm trying to implement a save feature into my game to save a variety of information. The save part works perfectly fine, but the load part does not work. This is my current dictionary:

```
player_data = {'x':x, 'y':y, 'world':mapSection, 'introcomplete':homeintro}
```

I am loading/saving with this:

```
def save_game():
    with open("savegame", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(player_data, f)
def load_game():
    with open("savegame", "rb") as f:
        global player_data
        player_data = pickle.load(f)
```

And to see what mapSection is set as, I use this:

```
load_game()
print(player_data)
if "1_1" in player_data:
    print('maploaded')
    game_map_1_1()
else:
    print('reset')
    game_intro()
```

But for some reason, it always skips over the if statement to the else statement. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you using `pickle`? I would recommend switching to JSON.

Comment: @Cyphase If you post comment like this, please say why exactly is pickle bad in this case. (IMHO it isn't)

Comment: @viraptor, I didn't say _it's bad_; I asked why OP is using it. Obviously I am recommending JSON, but there are reasons to use `pickle`, which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what you really want to do is check `player_data['world'] == '1_1'` and not `'1_1' in player_data`. The second one checks if you have a key named `1_1`.

This is not specific to pickle.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfect. I'm definitely going to get farther into game development thanks to you sir.